# need help with Workflow Rules formula

Tags: formula, workflow, field-update

I am working on a workflow rules assignment and I am stuck on a field updation task, I need to update a field called 'Trainer Category'  with values such as Platinum, Gold, Silver, and Bronze based on the experience of trainer.  With formula below, I am able to update the field with respective values but only when I am creating a new record. When edit/update the experience field there is no change in 'trainer category' value . Also, field updation works perfectly fine when I write 4 different rules for 4 values. Please help!!!

```
IF( Experience__c > 15,
'Platinum',
   IF( (Experience__c <=  15 && Experience__c > 10),
'Gold',
       IF( (Experience__c  <=  10 && Experience__c > 5),
'Silver',
           IF( Experience__c <=  5,'Bronze',null)
          )
       )
    )
```

Comment: Is trainer category Picklist field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing seems glaringly wrong with your formula but based on your question, it possibly could be an issue with how you set up the workflow. I don't fully know your use case so going to make few assumptions but starting from the top. First, you select the object the field is on and determine what user action will trigger the workflow. Your options are

a) created

b) created, and every time it's edited

c) created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria

It sounds like you want it to run when a record is created or updated so I'm going with B. Then you need to set the rule criteria. I set it to "Run this rule if the formula evaluates to true"

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Experience__c))
```

The formula will cause your workflow to run only when the 'Experience' field is not empty.

[image]

Next page is where you select what field you want the workflow to update, so in your case it'd be 'Trainer Category'. Then you add the formula to set the new value

```
 IF( Experience__c > 15,
'Platinum',
   IF( (Experience__c <=  15 && Experience__c > 10),
'Gold',
       IF( (Experience__c  <=  10 && Experience__c > 5),
'Silver',
           IF( Experience__c <=  5,'Bronze',null)
          )
       )
    )
```

Hit save and remember to activate your workflow. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Asheer for your help. Its working fine now, only change need was in Evaluation Criteria. I had selected 3rd option, when it should have been 2nd one. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @ManojPai Glad to hear. Please vote on the answer and mark it as accepted so others know this issue has been resolved